# Minecraft bukkit error handling players

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to set all players that are online to gamemode 0 (survival) (I do a varo plugin)

Here is [my code](https://hastebin.com/muparohiqi.cs):

```java
package com.abgelutscht.varo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.GameMode;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin{
    private int gamemode = 2;
    private int countdown = 30;
    private boolean countdownStarted = false;
    private boolean started = false;
    private Timer count = new Timer();
    private TimerTask count2 = new TimerTask(){
        public void run(){
            if(countdown>0){
                Bukkit.broadcastMessage(blue+"Noch "+aqua+countdown+blue+" Sekunden bis zum Start!");
                countdown--;
            }
            else{
                Bukkit.broadcastMessage(blue+"Los gehts!");
                startVaro();
                count.cancel();
            }
        }
    };
    private List<String[]> teams = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    public static final ChatColor dRed = ChatColor.DARK_RED;
    public static final ChatColor red = ChatColor.RED;
    public static final ChatColor aqua = ChatColor.AQUA;
    public static final ChatColor dAqua = ChatColor.DARK_AQUA;
    public static final ChatColor blue = ChatColor.BLUE;
    public static final ChatColor yellow = ChatColor.YELLOW;
    public static final ChatColor white = ChatColor.WHITE;
    private final String teamCommands = red+"Team-Befehle:\n"+blue
            + "/team " + dRed + "create " + red + "<" + aqua + "Teamname" + red + ">" + blue + "\n"
            + "/team " + dRed + "create " + red + "<" + aqua + "Teamname" + red + "> " + blue + red+ "<"+ dAqua+ "Spieler1" + red + "> " + blue + red+ "<"+ dAqua+ "Spieler2" + red + ">" + blue+ "\n"
            + "/team " + dRed + "add "    + red + "<" + aqua + "Teamname" + red + ">" + blue + " "+ red+ "<"+ dAqua+ "Spieler" + red + ">" + blue + "\n"
            + "/team " + dRed + "remove " + red + "<" + aqua + "Teamname" + red + ">" + blue + " "+ red+ "<"+ dAqua+ "Spieler" + red + ">" + blue + "\n"
            + "/team " + dRed + "delete " + red + "<" + aqua + "Teamname" + red + ">" + blue;
    @Override
    public void onEnable(){
        new PlayerListener(this);
        loadConfig();
        System.out.println("varo-plugin by abgelutscht enabled");
    }
    @Override
    public void onDisable(){
        writeConfig();
        System.out.println("varo-plugin by abgelutscht disabled");
    }
    private void loadConfig(){
        this.getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
        this.saveConfig();
        for(int i = 0; i < this.getConfig().getInt("length"); i++){
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list = getConfig().getStringList(String.format("%s", i));
            String[] team = new String[3];
            if(list.size()==1){
                team[0] = list.get(0);
            }
            else if(list.size()==2){
                team[0] = list.get(0);
                team[1] = list.get(1);
            }
            else if(list.size()==3){
                team[0] = list.get(0);
                team[1] = list.get(1);
                team[2] = list.get(2);
            }
            teams.add(team);
        }
        if(this.getConfig().getInt("countdown")!=0){
            countdown = this.getConfig().getInt("countdown");
        }
        started = this.getConfig().getBoolean("started");
        if(started){
            gamemode = 0;
        }
        if(!started){
            gamemode = 2;
        }
    }
    private void writeConfig(){
        this.getConfig().set("countdown", countdown);
        this.getConfig().set("started", started);
        this.getConfig().set("length", teams.size());
        for(int i = 0; i<teams.size(); i++){
            this.getConfig().set(""+i, teams.get(i));
        }
        this.getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
        this.saveConfig();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args){
        Player player = null;
        if(sender instanceof Player){
            player = (Player) sender;
        }
        if(command.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("team")){
            if(player.isOp()){
                if(!(args.length==0 || args.length>4)){
                    if(args.length==1){
                        if(args[0].equals("list")){
                            if(teams.size()!=0){
                                player.sendMessage(red+"Die Teams:\n");
                                for(int i = 0; i<teams.size(); i++){
                                    player.sendMessage(aqua+teams.get(i)[0]+blue+" "+teams.get(i)[1]+" "+teams.get(i)[2]+"\n");
                                }
                            }
                            else{
                                player.sendMessage(dRed+"[Fehler] Es existieren keine Teams!");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if(args.length==2){
                        if(args[0].equals("create")){
                            if(!teamExisting(args[1])){
                                String[] team = new String[3];
                                team[0] = args[1];
                                teams.add(team);
                                player.sendMessage(blue+"Das Team "+aqua+args[1]+blue+" wurde erstellt");
                            }
                            else{
                                player.sendMessage(dRed+"[Fehler] Das Team "+aqua+args[1]+dRed+" existiert bereits!");
                            }
                        }
                        else if(args[0].equals("remove")){
                            for(int i = 0; i<teams.size(); i++){
                                if(teams.get(i)[0].equals(args[1])){
                                    teams.remove(i);
                                    player.sendMessage(blue+"Das Team "+aqua+args[1]+blue+" wurde entfernt!");
                                }
                            }
                            if(teamExisting(args[1])){
                                player.sendMessage(dRed+"[Fehler] Das Team "+aqua+args[1]+dRed+" existiert nicht!");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if(args.length==3){
                        if(args[0].equals("add")){
                            for(int i = 0; i<teams.size(); i++){
                                if(teams.get(i)[0].equals(args[1])){
                                    if(teams.get(i)[1]!=null && teams.get(i)[2]!=null){
                                        player.sendMessage(dRed+"[Fehler] Das Team "+aqua+args[1]+dRed+" ist voll!");
                                    }
                                    else if(teams.get(i)[1]==null && teams.get(i)[2]==null){
                                        if(!playerExisting(args[2])){
                                            teams.get(i)[1] = args[2];
                                            player.sendMessage(blue+"Der Spieler "+aqua+args[2]+blue+" wurde zum Team "+aqua+args[1]+blue+" hinzugefügt!");
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            player.sendMessage(dRed+"[Fehler] Der Spieler "+aqua+args[2]+dRed+" ist bereits in einem anderen Team!");
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else if((teams.get(i)[1]!=null && teams.get(i)[2]==null) && !teams.get(i)[1].equals(args[2])){
                                        if(!playerExisting(args[2])){
                                            teams.get(i)[2] = args[2];
                                            player.sendMessage(blue+"Der Spieler "+aqua+args[2]+blue+" wurde zum Team "+aqua+args[1]+blue+" hinzugefügt!");
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            player.sendMessage(dRed+"[Fehler] Der Spieler "+aqua+args[2]+dRed+" ist bereits in einem anderen Team!");
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else if((teams.get(i)[1]!=null && teams.get(i)[2]==null) && teams.get(i)[1].equals(args[2])){
                                        player.sendMessage(dRed+"[Fehler] Der Spieler "+aqua+args[2]+dRed+" ist bereits in dem Team");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if(!teamExisting(args[1])){
                                player.sendMessage(dRed+"[Fehler] Das Team "+aqua+args[1]+dRed+" existiert nicht!");
                            }
                        }
                        else if(args[0].equals("remove")){
                            for(int i = 0; i<teams.size(); i++){
                                if(teams.get(i)[0].equals(args[1])){
                                    if(teams.get(i)[1]==null && teams.get(i)[2]==null){
                                        player.sendMessage(dRed+"[Fehler] Das Team "+aqua+args[1]+blue+" ist leer!");
                                    }
                                    else if(teams.get(i)[1]!=null && teams.get(i)[2]!=null){
                                        if(args[2].equals(teams.get(i)[1])){
                                            teams.get(i)[1] = teams.get(i)[2];
                                            teams.get(i)[2] = null;
                                            player.sendMessage(blue+"Der Spieler "+aqua+args[2]+blue+" wurde aus dem Team "+aqua+args[1]+blue+" entfernt!");
                                        }
                                        else if(args[2].equals(teams.get(i)[2])){
                                            teams.get(i)[2] = null;
                                            player.sendMessage(blue+"Der Spieler "+aqua+args[2]+blue+" wurde aus dem Team "+aqua+args[1]+blue+" entfernt!");
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else if((teams.get(i)[1]!=null && teams.get(i)[2]==null) && teams.get(i)[1].equals(args[2])){
                                        teams.get(i)[1] = null;
                                        player.sendMessage(blue+"Der Spieler "+aqua+args[2]+blue+" wurde aus dem Team "+aqua+args[1]+blue+" entfernt!");
                                    }
                                    else if(!args[2].equals(teams.get(i)[1]) && !args[2].equals(teams.get(i)[2])){
                                        player.sendMessage(dRed+"[Fehler] Der Spieler "+aqua+args[2]+dRed+" ist nicht in dem Team!");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if(!teamExisting(args[1])){
                                player.sendMessage(dRed+"[Fehler] Das Team "+aqua+args[1]+dRed+" existiert nicht!");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if(args.length==4){
                        if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("create")){
                            if(args[2]!=args[3] && (!playerExisting(args[2]) && !playerExisting(args[3])) && !args[2].equals(args[3])){
                                if(!teamExisting(args[1])){
                                    String[] team = new String[3];
                                    team[0] = args[1];
                                    team[1] = args[2];
                                    team[2] = args[3];
                                    teams.add(team);
                                    player.sendMessage(blue+"Das Team "+aqua+args[1]+blue+" wurde erstellt");
                                }
                                else{
                                    player.sendMessage(dRed+"[Fehler] Das Team "+aqua+args[1]+dRed+" existiert bereits!");
                                }
                            }
                            else if(args[2].equals(args[3])){
                                player.sendMessage(dRed+"[Fehler] Die Spieler "+aqua+args[2]+dRed+" und "+aqua+args[3]+dRed+" sind identisch!");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    player.sendMessage(teamCommands);
                }
            }
            else{
                player.sendMessage(dRed+"[Fehler] Du hast nicht die nötigen Rechte, diesen Befehl auszuführen!");
            }
        }
        if(command.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("countdown")){
            if(args.length==1){
                if(args[0].equals("start")){
                    if(!countdownStarted && !started){
                        countdownStarted = true;
                        count.schedule(count2, 0, 1000);
                    }
                    else{
                        player.sendMessage(dRed+"[Fehler] Der Countdown ist bereits gestartet worden!");
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(args.length==2){
                if(args[0].equals("set")){
                    if(!countdownStarted && !started){
                        try{
                            if(Integer.parseInt(args[1])<=0){
                                player.sendMessage(dRed+"[Fehler] Die Eingabe "+aqua+args[1]+dRed+" ist ungültig!");
                            }
                            else{
                                countdown = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
                                player.sendMessage(blue+"Der Countdown wurde auf "+aqua+args[1]+blue+" gesetzt!");
                            }
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){
                            player.sendMessage(dRed+"[Fehler] Die Eingabe "+aqua+args[1]+dRed+" ist ungültig!");
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        player.sendMessage(dRed+"[Fehler] Der Countdown ist bereits gestartet worden!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    private boolean playerExisting(String player){
        for(int i = 0; i<teams.size(); i++){
            try{
                for(int i2 = 0; i2<teams.get(i).length; i++){
                    if(player.equals(teams.get(i)[i2])){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){}
        }
        return false;
    }
    private boolean teamExisting(String team){
        for(int i = 0; i<teams.size(); i++){
            if(team.equals(teams.get(i)[0])){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    private void startVaro(){
        started = true;
        for(Player player: this.getServer().getOnlinePlayers()){
            player.setGameMode(GameMode.SURVIVAL);
        }
    }
    public List<String[]> getTeams(){
        return teams;
    }
    public int getGamemode(){
        return gamemode;
    }
}
```

If I start the countdown and the method startVaro() gets called I get [an error](https://hastebin.com/inovonuguc.md):

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0"
[20:04:39 WARN]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Asynchronous player tracker update!
[20:04:39 WARN]:        at org.spigotmc.AsyncCatcher.catchOp(AsyncCatcher.java:14)
[20:04:39 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.EntityTrackerEntry.updatePlayer(EntityTrackerEntry.java:313)
[20:04:39 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.EntityTracker.a(EntityTracker.java:207)
[20:04:39 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.EntityPlayer.B(EntityPlayer.java:1041)
[20:04:39 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.EntityPlayer.updateAbilities(EntityPlayer.java:934)
[20:04:39 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerInteractManager.setGameMode(PlayerInteractManager.java:36)
[20:04:39 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.entity.CraftPlayer.setGameMode(CraftPlayer.java:759)
[20:04:39 WARN]:        at com.x.varo.Main.startVaro(Main.java:304)
[20:04:39 WARN]:        at com.x.varo.Main.access$2(Main.java:300)
[20:04:39 WARN]:        at com.x.varo.Main$1.run(Main.java:31)
[20:04:39 WARN]:        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
[20:04:39 WARN]:        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Why do I have that error?  How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your problem is that you are trying to change player states asynchronously (relative to Bukkit's main thread). Have a look at [Scheduler Programming](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Scheduler_Programming) for details on how to schedule single or repeating Bukkit tasks. I believe that the most likely method you'd be interested in is `scheduleSyncDelayedTask()`

Comment: I tryed this now:

Comment: private void startVaro(){
  started = true;
  Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskAsynchronously(this, new Runnable(){
   public void run() {
    setAllGM0();
   }
  });
  protection.schedule(protection2, 0, 1000);
 }
 private void setAllGM0(){
  for(Player player: this.getServer().getOnlinePlayers()){
   player.setGameMode(GameMode.SURVIVAL);
  }
 }

But there is the same Exception

Comment: You are still running your task asynchronously by using `runTaskAsynchronously()`. The JavaDocs for this method specifically warns - *Asynchronous tasks should never access any API in Bukkit. Great care should be taken to assure the thread-safety of asynchronous tasks.*

As I hinted in my answer, `scheduleSyncDelayedTask()` is the method you want.

Comment: Detail your answer as mu ch as possible! The user shouldn't need to leave SO's site to check for your answer. What if the external site is offline now? How can that happen further users?

Comment: @Kerooker For the question asked, the detail is sufficient. OP's code shows some familiarity with spawning tasks. Having answered the primary question *Why do I have that error?* additional references were provided to allow OP get a better understanding of running tasks under Bukkit. There was no need to regurgitate what someone had already invested time to create and publish; nor, did it appear that OP required spoon feeding. If any Bukkit site goes offline, there will be far worse problems than having to click on a link.